# Mock method reported as called 0 times when it seems it MUST be being called at least once

Tags: mocking, phpunit

I have a method I'm mocking that is reported as being called 0 times, even though it seems certain it should be being called 1 times.

Here's my test class method (simplified):

```
function testFailedPasswordLogin() {
    $badPassword = 'NOT'.$this->testPassword;
    // setup a fake user repo that returns our test user (since we're passing valid username, just incorrect password)
    $this->Users = $this->getMock('Users', array('getByUsername'));
    $this->Users->method('getByUsername')->with($this->testUser->username)->willReturn(null);
    $this->Auth = new Auth($this->Users);
    $this->assertFalse($this->Auth->login($this->testUser->username,$badPassword));
    $loggedInUser = $this->Auth->user();
    $this->assertEquals(null, $loggedInUser);
}
```

UPDATE: I even decided to try using another mock framework (Prophecy):

```
$this->Users = $this->prophesize('Users');
$this->Users->getByUsername($this->testUser->username)->shouldBeCalled();
$this->Auth = new Auth($this->Users->reveal());
```

and I get exactly the same failure.

My class being tested (also simplified to just have the method and constructor):

```
class Auth {

    public function __construct(Users $Users) {
        $this->Users = $Users;
        $this->sessionKey = 'Auth.user';
    }

    public function login($username, $password) {
        $user = $this->Users->getByUsername($username);
        if ($user && ($user->password == $this->Users->hashPassword($password))) {
            $_SESSION[$this->sessionKey] = $user;
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }

    /** Get currently logged-in user **/
    public function user() {
        if (empty($_SESSION[$this->sessionKey])) return null;
        else return $_SESSION[$this->sessionKey];
    }

}
```

When running, I receive this error (slightly edited to show correctly here):

> There was 1 failure:
>
> 1) AuthTest::testFailedPasswordLogin
>   Expectation failed for method name is equal to string:getByUsername when
>   invoked 1 time(s).
>   Method was expected to be called 1 times, actually called 0 times.
>
> FAILURES!
>   Tests: 5, Assertions: 16, Failures: 1.

I am just about to pull out my hair on this one. I am admittedly just getting started using mocks but I can't for the life of me figure out why my mock method isn't being called.

I looked at both [PHPUnit mocked method called 0 times while it should be called once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21428327/phpunit-mocked-method-called-0-times-while-it-should-be-called-once) and [PHPUnit - Symfony2 : Method was expected to be called 1 times, actually called 0 times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30244097/phpunit-symfony2-method-was-expected-to-be-called-1-times-actually-called-0), and neither seems to address my specific problem.

I am running PHP 5.3.10 and PHPUnit 4.7.3.

Any help anyone can provide would be greatly appreciated to keeping my sanity. Any additional information that might be helpful, just let me know. I'm going to keep researching myself but so far I see no reason it shouldn't work based on the documentation.

Comment: And what happens if you would try to run the case with just the simplified example above? with php 5.5.9 & phpunit 4.7.3 the above example seems to run like expected...

Comment: @ejuhjav I simplified to the code above (previous edit was missing a called method: I added it as well above). Same result. I guess it could be because I'm running PHP 5.3? (that's what my server has). But other places I'm using mocked methods seem to work correctly.

Comment: I figured it out, I think. I had an expectation that getByUsername was to be called in my setUp(), and I figured I could just override it in my actual test method, but apparently it was instead expecting it to be called twice, then, and one call wasn't happening. This post should probably be deleted, unless it might be of benefit to someone else.